# Create a Command line program to encrypt and save user entered personal data

Tags: command-line, cryptography, amazon-kms, vault

How to create a Create a Command line program to encrypt and save user entered personal data

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.